# In DB, Is inefficient to compare with a Decimal field instead of an Integer? How much?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sqldatatypes

I have a table with records (could be few, or many), and in a certain situation I need to make a query against that table by parameters that can be Decimal or Integer, for example

```
select * from Table1 inner join Table2 on... 
where Table1.Field <= @Number
```

I can choose that "Field" be Decimal or Integer. Decimal is better for an algorith I'm implementing but I could use Integer also so... how inefficient is that query comparing use Decimal type versus Integer type? It does not matter? twice as slow? ten times slower?

Thanks

Comment: Just be sure that `field` and `@Number` have the same type.

Comment: I can't imagine that, in a modern system, the difference in performance for the numerical comparison would be at all significant compared to other aspects that affect the time of the transaction. If you're concerned you could always try each on a sample data set and measure.

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3323/comparing-sql-server-datatypes-size-and-performance-for-storing-numbers/). Depending on the scenario, just a few % slower for small result sets, or maybe two to three times as slow with huge ones. Also uses about twice the storage. As @lurker said, most likely there will be other parts of the transaction that will have much larger impact on performance.

Comment: @JacobH: the "twice the storage" is not true for Oracle. Oracle's `number` data type is a variable length data type that only uses as much space as needed. So storing `1` needs less space than storing `98765432`. Oracle also doesn't distinguish between an "integer" or a "decimal" - both are `NUMBER` data types with different constraints so in the end it's always a `NUMBER` compared to a `NUMBER`

Comment: The most important thing is that the field is indexed.

Comment: @carlosTI: which types exactly are you referring to? `NUMBER` vs e.g. `NUMBER(18,2)`? Because in Oracle,  `integer` is only an an alias for `NUMBER` and `decimal(x,y)` just an alias for `number(x,y)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't even see the oracle tag to be honest.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm talking about decimal (x,y)

Comment: @JacobH Thanks for article!!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is negligible. Use whichever type best represents the problem you have, and solves it correctly.

If you asked a question like this 30 years ago (no math co-processors) the answer could have been different, but not anymore.